# What are the possible values that GFileMonitorEvent can be in GNU GLib?

Tags: c, linux, glib, gnome

EDIT: Please see here https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776147

This may belong on Unix & Linux because it's about a GNOME library but I'm not sure.

I'm trying to figure out what are the possible states of GFileMonitorEvent in GLib because I'm trying to [solve a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfdesktop4/+bug/1598360) which has plagued me for years on Linux in which [the switch statement on lines 360-434](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gio/glocalfilemonitor.c) appears to reach the default state which causes the programs that I'm using to crash. Here's the error of one of the programs that crashes:

```
GLib-GIO:ERROR:/build/glib2.0-7IO_Yw/glib2.0-2.48.1/./gio/glocalfilemonitor.c:433:g_file_monitor_source_handle_event: code should not be reached
```

I already know that some of the states are G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CREATED, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGED, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_CHANGES_DONE_HINT, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED_IN, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED_OUT, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_RENAMED, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_DELETED, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_ATTRIBUTE_CHANGED, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_PRE_UNMOUNT, G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_UNMOUNTED, and G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED due to the switch statement's current conditions.

I have a feeling that if I can figure out what the missing possible states are then I might be able to just patch it myself to prevent from reaching this crashed state (but I could be [wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The available states are listed in the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileMonitor.html#GFileMonitorEvent). All the cases are handled so that means it has to be a G_FILE_MONITOR_EVENT_MOVED (despite the comment in source). You should probably file a bug on http://bugzilla.gnome.org -- the developers won't be looking in Ubuntu bug reports.

Comment: Good idea, here it is if you'd like to take a look: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776147